# Extract key value pair from dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm at the first step in programming and i'm stuck with a problem with Dictionary(key value) pair.
The statement of the problem is:

Write a console application that extracts and prints the key and value on a line.
Example:
For input data:
year:2018

The console will display:

> year
>
> 2018

here is my code:

```
        string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dictionary.Add(inputData, 2018 );

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: hi, thanks for help. The problem is: i have to write from the keybord " year:2018" , or" size:XL" and  i have to print " year" on the line and " 2018" on another line

Comment: It's not clear why you need a dictionary for that at all. Just use `inputData.Split(':')` and you'll get an array with two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// expects year:2018
var inputData = Console.ReadLine();

// split by ':' to get 'year' and '2018' values
var values = inputData.Split(':');

// creates a dictionary
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// add the 'year' string as key and '2018' as value
dictionary.Add(values[0], Convert.ToInt32(values[1]));

// print all the dictionary
foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

However, the problem description is not asking you to use a dictionary.
So, instead of creating a dictionary, you can simply print the values.

```
var inputData = Console.ReadLine();
var values = inputData.Split(':');
Console.WriteLine(values[0]);
Console.WriteLine(values[1]);
```

Comment: If they want a key-value pair, they want a map/dictionary.

Comment: "Write a console application that extracts and prints the key and value on a line." - extract, print, and ... done. The "year:2018" is the key/value. So, to achieve the solution, an explicit declaration of a dictionary is not necessary.